# Web Deployment Project "AfterBuild" in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, web-deployment-project

I am experimenting with the build file that is part of a web deployment project. My goal is do something in the "AfterBuild" target. I am doing the following.

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <MakeDir Directories="$(TargetDir)\Upload" />
</Target>
```

For some reason the folder never gets created. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just realized I have a slash before the word `upload` which isn't necessary and that is what was causing the issue.

```
"$(TargetDir)\Upload" <= wrong
"$(TargetDir)Upload" <= right
```